# Permissions to edit user field data, but not fields itself

Tags: 7, users

How to allow a role to edit/manage user accounts e.g. click Edit and change email, username, password etc., but do not edit the fields itself, e.g. cannot just go to `Manage fields` and delete/create/edit fields?

[Field permission](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions) doesn't do that, it's specifically just for each field per field.

Do not have access to `admin/config/people/accounts/fields` at all.
[image]

But they still can go to `admin/people` and update/manage users. So they still must have the `Administer users` permission
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Drupal 7, the permission to access admin/config/people/accounts is the same permission that allows to edit every account created on the site. The permission is returned by `user_entity_info()`, a [`hook_entity_info()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_entity_info/7.x) implementation. Any module that implements [`hook_entity_info_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_entity_info_alter/7.x), including a custom module, can alter what the User module returns in its hook implementation.

```php
/**
 * Implements hook_entity_info_alter().
 */
function mymodule_entity_info_alter(&$entity_info) {
  $entity_info['user']['bundles']['user']['admin']['access arguments'] = 'a new permission defined from the module';
}
```

The module must then implement [`hook_permission()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_permission/7.x) to define a new permission, keeping in mind that what I indicated with `'a new permission defined from the module'` is the new permission required to access *admin/config/people/accounts*.

Comment: Didn't use it, but I guess it wouldn't be fair accepting my own answer. Maybe this will help to others.

Answer (score 0):

Solved with Rules.

1. Action: Drupal is initializing
2. Condition: Text Comparison or Data Comparison, put in the URL path
3. Action: Page redirect.